# How to keep my application service always running in android2.1?

Tags: android, android-service, reminders

Hi i have written reminder code in service onstart().and when user insert date-time and insert record at that time service called by startservice() function,but only service is starting when i insert record i.e i am getting reminder when it get call from my activity.but i want reminder after 3days or something so how should i keep service always on so that i can get reminder in future? or how should i make connection of service keep alive?should i called bindservice() frunction from my any activity or what?
thanks in advance---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly no need of service,you can use[AlarManagerClass Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) Alarmanger class for schedule events and show alert at specific time and date. If you want show messages after some long duration then  schedule a Pending-intent via the AlarmManager thats starts the service at the relevant point in time to do it's work. When done, kill the service again as per tell by above answers . In  addition you can store your data into shared preferences for permanently. You can retrieve it at any time for resheulding it on device reboot or for other purpose.

Comment: how to restart() service after completing current task of service so that it will send message in future?

Comment: It is possible from braodcast reciever to start service on reboot.Check this http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/06/start-service-at-boot/

Comment: You can bind it again and then start the service.

Answer (score 2):

Don't let your Service run all the time. It consumes battery and memory when not neccessary¹.
Rather schedule a `PendingIntent` via the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) thats starts the service at the relevant point in time to do it's work. When done, kill the service again.

In general androids services are used different then services/daemons on a "normal" computer. They have a task that they execute, then they quit *(usually via `Service.stopSelf()`)* until someone starts them again to do more work.

Here is a small example how the AlarmManager is used:

```
// get a calendar with the current time
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
// add 15 minutes to the calendar object
cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 15);

Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, YourService.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(this, 123, intent, 
                                            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
```

This launches the intent to start `YourService` in 15 minutes from now. There is plenty of documentation for sending intents this way, search a bit around.

¹ *Which will eventually frustrate your users: "Why does this app waste my battery?" is a pretty common question*